# Images on same page as text (paragraph)

Tags: graphics, floats, page-breaking, paragraphs

I have 3 paragraphs with text (but without use \paragaph, just ext) and I have 3 images to these paragraphs. When I create pdf I have these paragraphs on one page (with text before) then on next page 2 images and some text which should be after all images and then on third page last image. So how can I do that every image should be on page where is text that belongs to this image. Or at least text would be between images.

My code now looks like this:

```
lorem ipsum .....
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
    {\includegraphics[width=12cm,keepaspectratio]{img/rest}}
    \caption{...}
    \label{rest}
  \end{center}
\end{figure} 

lorem ipsum ....
\begin{figure}[!h]
   \begin{center}
     {\includegraphics[width=12cm,keepaspectratio]{img/rest2}}
     \caption{...}
     \label{rest2}
   \end{center}
 \end{figure} 
...
```

Comment: Does the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use floats (`\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`) LaTeX places the figure at the first optimal place after where you type it in. You use `!h` to force the figure to be placed "exactly here" but this means "if possible" to LaTeX and is not as forcing as one might think.

If you absolutely need a figure to occur somewhere, one simple solution is to insert it without the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`, in other words not as a float.

There are also other solutions such as using the package `placeins` by using a comand `\FloatBarrier`. Another package to try is the `float` package which provides an `H` option which is similar to `!h`. In short, getting the pictures exactly where you want with floats is not trivial.

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` should be uppercase (`\Floatbarrier` doesn't exist)